# Custom fan page content is not displayed

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have Created a Custom Facebook application via Developer.facebook.com. I have added those application as a Facebook fan page but content is not displayed in custom Facebook fan page.
can any one guide me what is the problem?

My Canvas URL http://mytesting.my.phpcloud.com/controller/

and my Application URL is http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=107312062719767.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set both, Tab URL and Tab Secure URL? Supporting SSL is a requirement for all Apps. And if you have not set the Secure URL and you've enabled SSL for your Facebook account it won't display any content.

Comment: Yes i have added it all. dear anything else i have to for that??

Comment: "POST https://mytesting.my.phpcloud.com/controller/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)" this is the error I get in the console when trying to open the Tab, maybe an issue with your hoster?

Comment: Are you using this http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug link for debuging APplication?

Comment: No I used the Safari Developer Tools, the Facebook Debugger is just for Open Graph objects

Comment: i dont have safari installed in my pc. can u suggest me how can i check this in Chrome/Mozilla?? and by the way how can i resolve this issue "POST mytesting.my.phpcloud.com/controller 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Thanks  Björn Kaiser for guide me i have jst fixed those issue. :) kudos to you....

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can add the reason why it not worked and the solution so others can also profit :D

Comment: Actually this thig comes due to i am using php SlimFramework and routing a page as a get->request. so to come out this problem i allow both get and post request or method for Http Request. for More reference see this link 
http://www.slimframework.com/documentation/stable#method-not-allowed